# Create a field with grouped attributes from the model in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to group a specific attributes from a model instead of serializing them individually more or less like this

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    attr1 = models.IntegerField()
    attr2 = models.IntegerField()
    attr3 = models.CharField()
```

and serialize will output this

```
{
   # other attrs
   "grouped_attrs" : {"attr1": 23, "attr2": 848, "attr3": "foo"}
   # other attrs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can user [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for that.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    grouped_attrs = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('grouped_attrs')

    def get_grouped_attrs(obj):
        return {
            'attr1': obj.attr1,
            'attr2': obj.attr2,
            'attr3': obj.attr3
        }
```

Comment: is there some other way to achieve this without using method serializers? I don't like very much methods serializers